# How to Intercept image load requests in WebView?

Tags: iphone, image, request, webview, intercept

Is it possible to intercept image load requests in WebView before they are actually started and modify their URLs?

For example, I have

```
mWebView.loadUrl(myUrl);
```

In onLoadResources event I can see URLs, but I can't modify them?

The thing is I am working on application that loads html content from remote location. For some reason author excluded image path and in img src he just have file name. Existing iPhone application is using this html content and I assume the content is build the way that is the best for iPhone. So, I need somehow to figure how to alter these paths. For example, if I choose to download all images first, I would need to alter path and add file:///... in front of image.jpg name.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can use onLoadResource although are not only images but any resource loaded like javascript and css